# NHibernate 2.1: LEFT JOIN on SubQuery with Alias (ICriteria)

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, subquery, left-join, alias

I am basically trying to create this query with NHibernate ICriteria interface:

SomeTable 1:n AnotherTable

**SomeTable** has columns: PrimaryKey, NonAggregateColumn
**AnotherTable** has columns: PrimaryKey, ForeignKey, AnotherNonAggregate, YetAnotherNonAggregate

```
SELECT 
      table1.NonAggregateColumn, 
      subquery.SubQueryAggregate1, 
      subquery.SubQueryAggregate2
FROM 
      SomeTable AS table1
      LEFT JOIN
      (
          SELECT 
                table2.ForeignKey,
                COUNT(table2.AnotherNonAggregate) AS SubQueryAggregate1,
                AVG(table2.YetAnotherNonAggregate) AS SubQueryAggregate2
          FROM AnotherTable AS table2
          GROUP BY (table2.ForeignKey)
      ) AS subquery ON subquery.ForeignKey = table1.PrimaryKey
```

It is clear that using Projection subquery is not very efficient, since SQL has to scan the table twice (one projection subquery per aggregate).

Using multiple GROUP BYs is not efficient as well.

Is there a solution for this ? So far I've been resorting to using raw SQL but this is getting unwieldy for complex reports.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The query you are showing is native sql. Does it already return the expected data? You want to turn it to criteria. Why not HQL?

Comment: Forgot to mention: you are using a ORM. So to write a query, you don't have to care too much about the tables and foreign key. Much more important are the entities and mapping definitions. So how are these to tables mapped? Is there a list in SomeTable? Is there a reference in AnotherTable? Or both?

Comment: Yes, the original query returns the needed data for a report. I am using NHibernate 2.1. Criteria API is preferred because of strong-typing ability via NHLambdaExtensions (which I am also using). 

I am using the names SomeTable, AnotherTable in order to make the SQL clear and easy to read. It is a fictitious mirror of real objects.

SomeTable mapped object has an inverse one-to-many collection of AnotherTable objects.

Comment: No one has any ideas ? nobody ever tried this before ?

Comment: Can you post the criteria and/or HQL code for this query?  I would very much like to see it (even if it performs poorly). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Criteria is a bit restricted.

Try this:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SomeTable), "st")
  .SetProjection( Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("st.id"))
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("st.NonAggregateColumn"))
    .Add(Projections.RowCount(), "rowcount")
    .Add(Projections.Avg("at.YetAnotherNonAggregate"), "avg"));
  .CreateCriteria( "st.OtherTables", "at", JoinType.InnerJoin)
  .List<object[]>();
```

You probably need to play around a bit, it's more of a guess. It also might be impossible this way.

It should produce something like this:

```
select
  st.id,
  st.NonAggregateColumn,
  count() as "rowcount",
  avg(at.YetAnotherNonAggregate) as "avg"
from
  SomeTable st inner join AnotherTable at on ...
group by
  st.id,
  st.NonAggregateColumn
```

Generally:

- You can make subqueries using `DetachedCriteria`. See [the docs](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-13/1nr4enxv3dpeq/16?collectionId=1ymgfl6mjzmm7.1#13%282E%298%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Detached_queries_and_subqueries) for more details.
- You can't make a cartesian product with Criteria and filter in the where clause. (This only works with HQL).
- Subqueries can not be added to the from clause (because that would result in a cartesian product). You can only put them to the where clause (`in`, `exists` etc.)
- You could probably start with `AnotherTable` and navigate to `SomeTable`. This might be a alternative solution.

Comment: I'm aware of the group by solution, but the problem is that in the real world report, I would need to group by so many columns, that SQL is going to slow down a great deal for 1000s of records, oh well, maybe I can try to study NHibernate's source and contribute this one day...

I'll use raw SQL for now then, thanks for the help.