# Order By Aggregate Subquery with NHibernate ICriteria or QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, aggregate, icriteria, queryover

Is there a way to achieve SQL like this with NHibernate ICriteria or QueryOver?

```
select *
  from [BlogPost] b
  inner join (select blogpost_id, count(*) matchCount
                from [Tag]
                where name in ('tag X', 'tag Y')
                group by blogpost_id
             ) tagmatch 
  on tagmatch.blogpost_id = b.Id
  order by tagmatch.matchCount desc
```

The aim is to rank blog posts by the number of matching tags so that a post with both *tag X* and *tag Y* comes above posts with just *tag X*.

I've got this so far:

```
 DetachedCriteria
                .For<Tag>("tag")
                .Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property<Tag>(x => x.Name), tags.ToArray()))
                .SetProjection(Projections.Group<Tag>(t => t.BlogPost))
                    .CreateCriteria("BlogPost")
                    .SetFetchMode("BlogPost", FetchMode.Eager)
                .AddOrder(Order.Desc(Projections.RowCount()));
```

However, the resulting query doesn't join fetch `BlogPost`. Instead it returns just the ids, which leads to select n+1 when the `BlogPost`s are iterated.

```
public class BlogPost
{
  ...
  ISet<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
}

public class Tag
{
  BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[This  looks like a similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373539/nhibernate-2-1-left-join-on-subquery-with-alias-icriteria)

**Is this now possible with NHibernate 3?**

**If not, is there an alternative solution?**

I can change schema & domain model if necessary. I don't want to use SQL or HQL if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question was put some time ago, but I want to do about the same thing, please take a look to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153819/nhibernate-queryover-join-with-subquery-to-get-aggregate-column), and this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333217/get-children-count-with-restrictions-using-queryover-on-nhibernate), maybe you can use the idea.

Comment: My issue was resolved by changing the db schema, but the answers you have linked to look like they would solve the problem I had.