# NHibernate QueryOver Join to subquery

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, queryover

Is there anyway to do a join to a select statement using NHibernate (QueryOver if possible)?

Here is the SQL I'm hoping to generate

```
SELECT r.MaxReading, r.MeterId, m.PreviousHours
FROM 
 Meters m
 LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT Max(mr.ReadingHours) as MaxReading, mr.AssetMeterId
    FROM MeterReadings mr
    WHERE mr.MeterId IN(1,2)
    GROUP BY mr.MeterId) r
 ON m.Id=r.MeterId
```

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153819/nhibernate-queryover-join-with-subquery-to-get-aggregate-column) post, but it looks like the answer was to build a different query.  Which makes me think this may not be possible.

I already figured out how to build the subquery piece, so any answer can just use a simple query in it's place as an example. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your class definitions and mappings, as the possible queries will highly  depend on it. 
What is `mr.AssetMeterId` in your subquery ? It does not seem to appear in the group by and seems to be referred to as `r.MeterId` in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's impossible to join on a subquery in NHibernate since all joins must come from relations in your object model.